# About python's module import system

Tags: python

I have some questions about python's system of modules and importing them. I have following structure of my app:

```
preloader/   
    preload.py
    Core/
        Generator.py
        Logger.py
        ErrorHandling.py
    Libraries/
        MySQLi.py
        memcached.py
```

`__init__.py` files are present inside every folder even on root level, omitted from structure for better readability.

Inside `preload.py` I want to import the `memcached` module. So I write `from Libraries import memcached`. Inside `memcached.py` I have class named `Memcached`. So when I have to instantiate it I have to write something like this `mem = memcached.Memcached()`. How can I avoid writing `modulename.classname()` and just do `classname()`?

Also I tried this inside preload.py `from preloader.Libraries.memcached import Memcached`. That gave me no such module error!!

Another question. Someone please shine some light on relative imports. `preload.py` has a class inside it named `ThreadManager` I want this class inside `ErrorHandling.py`. How can I achieve that? I tried with relative imports `from .. import preload`. Then when I run `preload.py` I get error `ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package`. Then I tried `from preload import ThreadManager`. But then it's taking circular imports so I can't import it. How to solve this problem?

python version 2.7.3

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `from package.module import names` syntax for your `Memcached` class:

```
from Libraries.memcached import Memcached
```

then use `Memcached` instead of `memcached.Memcached` in your code.

If you need to use `ThreadManager` from another module, and you run into a circular import, then you should re-organize your modules. Move `ThreadManager` to a new module, and import that class from both `preload` and from `Core.ErrorHandling`.

Comment: that gave me `ImportError: No module named memcached` error !!

Comment: doing that I get. `ImportError: cannot import name Memcached`. I will be honest with you. It's been like 2-3 weeks since I have started working in python. But I have so far been unable to understand the mystical ways in which python's module import moves!! :P

Comment: Strange you are getting a `cannot import name Memcached`. Doublecheck it is correctly spelled; it is finding the module, just not the `Memcached` class contained *in* the `Library/memcached.py` file.

Comment: yes, I have checked the name. Spelled correctly. Still something like this. This is the same case with the box that work on in my office.